# eBay Trading API AddFixedPriceItem call returns 'Input data is invalid' error

Tags: xml, ebay-api

I want to create a bot to automate the listing procedure on eBay.in. I am testing various calls to develop a template for my bot which will fetch data from my database and send it to eBay. I have been trying to list a new product in sandbox provided by eBay.

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>Token Already Inserted Here</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<!-- Call-specific Input Fields -->
<Item>
    <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    <Country>IN</Country>
    <Currency>INR</Currency>
    <Description>This Is Description</Description>
    <InventoryTrackingMethod>SKU</InventoryTrackingMethod>
    <DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
    <OutOfStockControl>true</OutOfStockControl>
    <PaymentMethods>CreditCard</PaymentMethods>
    <PaymentMethods>DirectDebit</PaymentMethods>
    <PictureDetails>
      <GalleryURL>http://cdn3.purplle.com/static/img/cache/product/PPLB121HD110/250x250_1.jpg?1390916568</GalleryURL>
    </PictureDetails>
    <PostalCode>400086</PostalCode>
    <PrimaryCategory>
         <CategoryID>11858</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingService>In_Courier</ShippingService>
            <ShippingServiceCost>49.0</ShippingServiceCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <ShipToLocations>IN</ShipToLocations>
    <!--more ShipToLocations values allowed here-->
    <Site>India</Site>
    <SKU>PPLB121HD110</SKU>
    <StartPrice>2258.00</StartPrice>
    <!--SubTitle> string </SubTitle-->
    <Title>Braun Satin Hair 1 Dryer HD 110 Hair Dryer</Title>
</Item>
<!-- Standard Input Fields -->
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<!--MessageID> string </MessageID>
<Version> string </Version-->
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>​
```

Now after doing many modification in xml request, the above one is the latest one. I get following error response on submitting the above request everytime.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddFixedPriceItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2014-06-24T07:19:29.784Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Input data is invalid.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Input data for tag &lt;Item.ShippingDetails&gt; is invalid or missing. Please check API documentation.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>37</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorParameters ParamID="0">
        <Value>Item.ShippingDetails</Value>
        </ErrorParameters>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>873</Version>
    <Build>E873_UNI_API5_16868630_R1</Build>
</AddFixedPriceItemResponse>​
```

I have done all the google search, went through all the api, tried to copy the sample code but still i get the same error.
I am wondering if their is some error in xml or anything else that i might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for `ShippingService` is case sensitive, I think you have to use "IN_Courier" with an uppercase "N".

A list of valid options for `ShippingService` you'll find here:

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/types/ShippingServiceCodeType.html

Comment: now following error occured
<ShortMessage>Payment method is missing.</ShortMessage>

Comment: Then you should supply a payment method: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html#Request.Item.PaymentDetails